# mysql query o retrieve records based on the following conditions

Tags: mysql

Please help me with a mysql query, using PHP to access databse and process data:

I have variables

```
1) $content_number_of_characters
2) $number_of_comments
```

and mysql table name: `udjacomments`

fields of table udjacomments: `id, full_name, content, comment_url, is_published, and time_added`

I would like to retrieve each entry into an array. For content, I would like to only get the content up to the character `$content_number_of_characters` (In other words, if $content_number_of_characters is 120, and content is 300 characters, I only want the first 120 characters).

(I do not know how I could use the mysql LEFT(str, len) into the query)

Then, I only want number of records ( `$number_of_comments` ) in a descending order from id  and if field is_published == 1

Example:

I have records with id: 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56
all records have is_published == 1, with the exception of record with id 55; record id 55 is_published == 0. Last, variable `$number_of_comments` == 3

the query would retrieve records 56, 54, and 53

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Number of comments:

   $query = "SELECT * FROM udjacomments 
             where is_published = 1 order by id desc limit $number_of_comments"
2. 120 chars

   $query = "select id, 
            if(CHAR_LENGTH(content) > $content_number_of_characters, SUBSTR(content, 1, $content_number_of_characters), content) 
            FROM udjacomments";

Comment: THANK YOU   could the query be: $query = "SELECT id, full_name,  if(CHAR_LENGTH(content) > $content_number_of_characters, SUBSTR(content, 1, $content_number_of_characters), content), comment_url, is_published, and time_added FROM udjacomments where is_published = 1 order by id desc limit $number_of_comments" In other words, can I merged the two queries you porpose into one... I am testing right now

Comment: THANX I used your suggestions, and merged the query. This was my final query:    $query  = "SELECT id, full_name, if(CHAR_LENGTH(content) > ".$content_number_of_characters.", SUBSTR(content, 1, ".$content_number_of_characters."), content), comment_url, time_added FROM udjacomments where is_published = 1 order by id DESC limit ".$number_of_comments;